# Meaning of 'すれ違う赤の軌道'

Tags: translation, meaning, words, usage, kanji

I don't really get the meaning of this line 'すれ違う赤の軌道'
Could it mean 'Crimson path crossed' or 'The crimson path i crossed' ?

Comment: I was looking for some more context and I found out that the sentence you are asking about is probably part of the lyrics of a song called "Brave Shine". I have found a full translation of the lyrics here: http://leirion63.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-21.html The whole translation is not perfectly literal though, but I think in general it makes sense and it might put you on the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> すれ違う赤の軌道
> ```

Words:

> すれ違う: Two things passing or missing one another. In my opinion this
>   can have a romantic or at least emotional connotation, as in "so
>   close, but so far!"
>
> 赤: red
>
> 軌道: orbit, often the orbit of a planet or other celestial body

The link given by Tommy (converted to a comment) is a good start, but the translation is somewhat non-literal.

A slightly more literal translation of this part could be:

> Red orbits, passing either other by